# BigQuery: Why when I try execute query give me the error Not found: Dataset was not found in location US

Tags: google-bigquery

The situation is, when I execute this query (`` select query from `bigquery-analytics-workbench.team_bi._airflow_logs_tests ``) I have the next result:
[image: Result of query]

and I want execute the query saved inside of this column, but when I execute this query, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE select query from bigquery-analytics-workbench.team_bi._airflow_logs_tests limit 1` return the error `Not found: Dataset bigquery-analytics-workbench:team_bi was not found in location US at [1:1]`

Comment: Have a look here on how to set the region via SQL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509831/13028724

Comment: You can set the location via SQL as follows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71509831/13028724

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery Query Settings, the Processing Location of the queries is by default set on `Auto-Select`. Auto-select determines the processing location by the location of the dataset that you are querying. As a result, when you are using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with the query provided as a string, it's not possible to determine the correct processing location so it falls back to `US` as default. Since your dataset `team_bi` is not in the `US`, you get this error.

You can work around that by specifying the processing location in the Query Settings to the one where your dataset is located.